# How do I benchmark cached jQuery DOM selection in JSPerf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to test how caching my DOM selection (assigning the selection to a var) is performing over my old JS code. I tried using JSPerf, but it seems to just run everything in a loop, which means my var assignment is getting duplicated thousands of times. How can I fix this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/Y5w5r/6/) for my updated code

Script for benchmark (old code) #1:

```
$('.projectscontainer').on("click", "span.destproject", function () {
    $(this).siblings('.projectschildren').toggle().end().siblings('div.destarrow').toggleClass("arrow-right arrow-down");
}).on("click", "div.destarrow", function () {
    $(this).parent().find("span.destproject").trigger("click");
});

$('body').on("click", "span#expandcollapse", function () {
    if ($(this).text() === 'Expand All') { //Currently collapsed
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        $('.projectscontainer').find("div.destarrow").filter('.arrow-right').toggleClass("arrow-right arrow-down");
        $('.projectscontainer').find(".projectschildren").toggle(true);
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('Action took: ' + (endTime - startTime) + 'ms');
    } else { //Currently expanded            
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        $('.projectscontainer').find("div.destarrow").filter('.arrow-down').toggleClass("arrow-down arrow-right");
        $('.projectscontainer').find(".projectschildren").toggle(false);
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('Action took: ' + (endTime - startTime) + 'ms');
    }
    $(this).text(function (i, currentText) {
        return currentText === 'Expand All' ? 'Collapse All' : 'Expand All';
    });
});
```

Script for benchmark (new code) #2:

```
var projectscontainer = $('body').find('div.projectscontainer');
var projectschildren  = projectscontainer.find("div.projectschildren");
var destarrows        = projectscontainer.find("div.destarrow");
var srcprojects       = projectscontainer.find("div.srcprojects");

projectscontainer.on("click", "span.destproject", function (){
    $(this).siblings('div.projectschildren').toggle().end().siblings('div.destarrow').toggleClass("arrow-right arrow-down");
}).on("click", "div.destarrow", function (){
    $(this).parent().find("span.destproject").trigger("click");
});

$('body').on("click", "#expandcollapse", function (){
    if($(this).text() === 'Expand All'){//Currently collapsed
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        destarrows.filter('div.arrow-right').toggleClass("arrow-right arrow-down");
        projectschildren.toggle(true);
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('Action took: ' + (endTime - startTime) + 'ms');
    } else {//Currently expanded            
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        destarrows.filter('div.arrow-down').toggleClass("arrow-down arrow-right");            
        projectschildren.toggle(false);
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('Action took: ' + (endTime - startTime) + 'ms');
    }
    $(this).text(function(i, currentText){
        return currentText === 'Expand All' ? 'Collapse All' : 'Expand All';
    });
});
```

JSPerf benchmarks end up running these lines

```
var projectscontainer = $('body').find('div.projectscontainer');
var projectschildren  = projectscontainer.find("div.projectschildren");
var destarrows        = projectscontainer.find("div.destarrow");
var srcprojects       = projectscontainer.find("div.srcprojects");
```

over and over (along with all the other code), while in my original code, it's only run once. How do I get it to only run once instead of running repeatedly?

Comment: You put those variables in the `Define setup for all tests` section. Can you make a JSPerf test and link me to it?

Comment: Oh, makes sense now. Here's the link to the test: http://jsperf.com/testing-cached-dom-selection-v2 Thanks!